# pipe array of json objects as a map of single post, using curl

Tags: linux, json, shell, curl, pipe

I have a two nodes having same rest+json api ( not jsonapi.org btw )

One of them has many products in /products
The other has [] in /products

I want to pipe products of one node ( say: `http://localhost:9080/products` ) into the other one ( say `http://localhost:8080/products` )

Operation **MUST** happen on command line

### This should be a solved problem ?

I think so, but I does not know it yet and have not find a solution yet...

### what I experimented that work and found ugly

```
for f in $( curl http://localhost:9080/products | jq -c '.[]' | sed -e 's/ /\\_/g' ); do echo $f | sed -e 's/\\_//g' | curl -i -H Content-Type:application/json http://localhost:8080/products --data @-; done
```

the above uses [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) as a json parser

`curl http://localhost:9080/products | jq -c '.[]'` actually emits each products of collection

the ugly `sed` hack is meant to tackle label fields that are like

```
"label":"what is your favorite color?"
```

It does the job on a small set of products, and still I'm not happy with it

What did I miss ?

### What I expect of a response

- should perform as "fast" as the above one ( I'm a rubyist )
- should not be longer, in chars, than the above one or should be clearer

Comment: If you know Ruby, why don't you write a ruby script? `ruby -rjson -rnet/http 'json=JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get(URI("http://localhost:9080/products"))); ...'`

Comment: because ruby is slow :)

Comment: more seriously, ruby has a slow startup for a command line ( compare curl with ruby -e 'curl' + require time... ). we might not need ruby for a loop/each

Comment: depending on how many products you have, I'd guess the cost of launching one ruby process would be insignificant compared to posting hundreds of products to a web server. But, you don't know unless you try a few different methods.

Comment: Anyway, to get more serious help, you'll probably need to show some of the JSON and what the `jq` output looks like.